# How to resolved OnClick method click issue , it is not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-button

I have defined an `onclick` function as `clickFunction`. I'm new at coding and Android Studio.

Why does below code not work?

```
package com.example.learnerapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void clickFunction(View view){
        Log.i( tag: "info", msg: "booyaa");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail - in what way doesn't it work? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir may be he forgot to write  android:onClick="clickFunction" in XML file so click not working.

Comment: "Android studio beginner" is definitely not a proper title for a question. :) It doesn't really describe the problem in any way.

Comment: Are you calling that method? It seems like you're only declaring it in the code above.

Comment: My answer is perfect for you pls check and  mark as a right if it helpful to you.

Comment: @InsaneCat: Maybe, but it's hard to tell based on what's in the question, and a complete lack of description of what's meant by "not working".

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir , Hmmm you are right need more description , hope his issue resolved by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think better to follow a button example as when u click the button it will do something.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;
public class yourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    Button yourbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something here
         } 
    });
}
```

and add this to yourActivity.xml

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/yourbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="what you want to do?"            
 />
```